# How to remove page from Navigation History?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

How do I remove a page from the Navigation History?

I go forward like this:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(...));
```

But what I want is

> A -> B -> C -> D -> E

Back?

> E -> A

So I want to delete the Backward Navigation Stack. NavigationService is not available in Windows 8 as far as I know. And I don't find any useful function in the page class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [Frame.SetNavigationState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.setnavigationstate). When you're on page `A`, store [Frame.GetNavigationState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.getnavigationstate.aspx) in a static variable which is accessible anywhere in the app.

```
MyClass.PageANavigationState = Frame.GetNavigationState();
```

When you're on `E` (or whichever page), and you want to clear the navigation stack up to `A`, use

```
Frame.SetNavigationState[MyClass.PageANavigationState];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and I done this using the below code

```
while (Frame.BackStackDepth > 0)
{
    if (Frame.CanGoBack)
    {
        Frame.GoBack();
    }
}
Frame.CacheSize = 0;
Frame.Navigate(typeof(LoginScreen));
```

Answer (score 0):

On UWP, `Frame.BackStack.Clear()` works fine (since it's `IList<PageStackEntry>`).

Also, you may use other `IList` methods (such as `RemoveAt`) to accomplish your task.